# How to save the Google map location with mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I Want to save my address to database and show them on Google map but I dont want to use latitude and longitude method. Since there is couple of example I seen but most of them asking latitude and longitude to user who will save the data. But assume that the user doesn't know about anything what the latitude and longitudes inputs are and they just want to write down to adres or choose in from Google map?  What is the solution for that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at this

[Google Geo Coding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Below is a small example , hope you have studied google map API already

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }// initial coords as default
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        directionsService.route({
            origin: Address here ,
            destination: Address here,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that google  map API implemantation exist in that way. I have worked couple of google map API and I figure out how do. Thank you you saved hours.

Comment: @Emre if it does solve your problem than dont forget to upvote and Mark as answer